# Error: pg_config executable not found in Postgres Docker container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-container

Probably my question is repeated

I am using Postgres with Docker on MacOs

I am not doing it with `Dockerfile`

```
docker pull postgres:10
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres10 -v /Users/myuser/Volumes/postgres10:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -d postgres:10
```

I am trying to install `psycopg2` in a flask application with`Python 3.7`

But it doesn't find `pg_config`

I know that in a traditional installation it is located in `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"`

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: It's a C library dependency, and you have to install it in your Flask image (or an earlier stage of it).  It doesn't have anything to do with where the database is ultimately running.

Comment: @DavidMaze I had already seen that answer, but he is using `Dockerfile`

Comment: How are you running your Flask application, without a Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze exactly that's it, without Dockerfile

Comment: Without a Dockerfile, how are you managing to run your Flask application?  What image are you using, and how does your code get there?  `docker build` is a very standard part of Docker and you'll need a custom image if you have C dependencies like this.

Comment: Well the flask app is separate, as it is traditionally used in development, I am trying this since previously in another app I used flask with elasticsearch and without problems it was connected, I thought that for postgres it would be the same.